# Error Happend after calling send mail procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created a procedure named as send_mail in sql developer oracle which is written below.

```
create or replace procedure Send_Mail(Msg_To varchar2, Msg_Subject varchar2, Msg_Text varchar2) is

    c        Utl_Smtp.Connection;
    Rc       integer;
    Msg_From varchar2(50) := 'it.dev23@dawateislami.net'; -- email of my company which hosted on Gmail
    Mailhost varchar2(30) := 'smtp.gmail.com';


begin
    c := Utl_Smtp.Open_Connection(Mailhost, 587);
    Utl_Smtp.Ehlo(c, Mailhost);
    Utl_Smtp.StartTLS(c);
    Utl_Smtp.Ehlo(c, Mailhost);
    Utl_Smtp.Mail(c, Msg_From);
    Utl_Smtp.Rcpt(c, Msg_To);

    Utl_Smtp.Data(c,
                  'From: Oracle Database' || Utl_Tcp.Crlf || 'To: ' || Msg_To || Utl_Tcp.Crlf || 'Subject: ' || Msg_Subject || Utl_Tcp.Crlf ||
                  Msg_Text);
    Utl_Smtp.Quit(c);

exception
    when Utl_Smtp.Invalid_Operation then
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(' Invalid Operation in Mail attempt 
using UTL_SMTP.');
    when Utl_Smtp.Transient_Error then
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(' Temporary e-mail issue - try again');
    when Utl_Smtp.Permanent_Error then
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(' Permanent Error Encountered.');
end;
```

And when i am trying to  call the procedure to send email it gives error please help me out i want to send email .let me know where is my mistake.
I have grant all commands

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_TCP  TO admonline;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_SMTP TO admonline;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_MAIL TO admonline;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_http TO admonline;
--Calling procedure
BEGIN
send_mail(msg_to      => 'waqasprince911@gmail.com',
          msg_subject => 'Test subject',
          msg_text    => 'Test text');
END;
```

Error is Mention

```
 Certificate validation failure
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 59
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 284
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 284
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 289
    ORA-06512: at "ADMONLINE.SEND_MAIL", line 11
    ORA-06512: at line 2
    29024. 00000 -  "Certificate validation failure"

    *Cause:    The certificate sent by the other side could not be validated. This may occur if
               the certificate has expired, has been revoked, or is invalid for another reason.

    *Action:   Check the certificate to determine whether it is valid. Obtain a new certificate,
               alert the sender that the certificate has failed, or resend.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear. Try googliing for UTL_SMTP , certificate and 29024. 00000 -  "Certificate validation failure"  also read the docs on how to use this package. It would seem to be a failure of the security certificate.

A quick google turned up [this](http://%20http://all-dba.blogspot.com/2014/11/ora-29024-certificate-validation.html),

Also, as a noob, remember you are asking us to take time out of our day to help you. Help us by always including version of product and what steps you have tried and the result and what searches and investigation you have tried.

these may help:
https://mathijsbruggink.com/2013/10/24/sending-mail-from-an-11g-oracle-database-utl_smtp/  https://community.oracle.com/thread/930797  http://www.dadbm.com/enable-oracle-database-to-send-emails-via-smtp-server/  https://community.oracle.com/thread/368259

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4089002  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS074
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql

Comment: i am using oracle 11g and using apex 18.2 version i had tried many procedures but it never give me output..steps and the way of practices has been mentioned and i had also tried most of the steps from google.

Comment: I don't do this myself, but some things that come to mind are: Since the email is being sent by the database kernel, is the database setup to send email correctly? Has this been tested and confirmed? Next is to post ion the Oracle help forums, check My Oracle Support and lastly, bring in a consultant who knows what they are doing.